# Doctrine Default Annotation Namespace in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to embark on ZF2 since they've moved to RC status. Everything is going smoothly, but I'd like to set a default namespace for annotations so I can use `@Table` instead of `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table` or `@ORM\Table`.

From what I can tell reading the Doctrine module's documentation in their [readme on Github](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule), there is no option that allows you to specify default namespaces to the reader or even specify your own reader class. Does anyone know if this option is simply missing at this time? Or is there something I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam said, use statements are the normal way to handle annotation namespaces.

If you want to use a different Annotation Reader, then write a new `DriverFactory` to replace the one that ships with DoctrineModule, and override the module config so that your new factory is used. (If you think your new factory might be useful to others, feel free to put in a PR against DoctrineModule and share)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't realize the module was doing the factory stuff. That got me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the Annotations are defined by the way you handle the use-statements of your class. Currently you do `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM` so the annotation grabs `@ORM` and everything past that is simply concatenated.

So `@ORM\Table` becomes `Doctrime\ORM\Mapping\Table`

My guess - but i haven't tested this - if you include the Table class via `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table` that `@Table` would work. Just a humble guess though. As you've pointed out, there are not all too many ressources for ZF2 Implementations, yet, and quality of life features always come last ;)

Comment: If you use `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader` versus the standard `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader`, you can specify a default namespace. That way you can give the reader a default namespace of `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping` and use `@Table` without all the use statements. I guess my real question is how I can use `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader` instead of `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader`. But as you said, convenience options always come last...